# How do I configure elastic search to use the icu_tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search a text indexed by elasticsearch and the icu_tokenizer but can't get it working.

My testcase is to tokenize the sentence “Hello. I am from Bangkok”, in thai สวัสดี ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ, which should be tokenized to the five words สวัสดี, ผม, มา, จาก, กรุงเทพฯ. ([Sample from Elasticsearch - The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/icu-tokenizer.html))

Searching using any of the last four words fails for me. Searching using any of the space separated words สวัสดี or ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ works fine.

If I specify the icu_tokenizer on the command line, like

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/icu/_analyze?tokenizer=icu_tokenizer' -d "สวัสดี ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ"
```

it tokenizes to five words.

My settings are:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/icu/_settings?pretty
{
  "icu" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1474010824865",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "nfkc_cf_normalized" : [ "icu_normalizer" ],
            "tokenizer" : "icu_tokenizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards" : "5",
      "number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "uuid" : "tALRehqIRA6FGPu8iptzww",
      "version" : {
        "created" : "2040099"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The index is populated with

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/icu/employee/' -d '
{
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Doe",
  "about" :  "สวัสดี ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ"
}'
```

Searching with

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search' -d'
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "about" : "กรุงเทพฯ"
    }
  }
}'
```

Returns nothing ("hits" : [ ]).
Performing the same search with one of สวัสดี or ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ works fine.

I guess I've misconfigured the index, how should it be done?

Comment: I found out I was missing the mapping part

Comment: what exactly were you missing? would help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is:

```
  "mappings": {
    "employee" : {
      "properties": {
        "about":{
          "type": "text", 
          "analyzer": "icu_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In the mapping, the document field have to be specified the analyzer to be using.

[Index] : icu

[type] : employee

[field] : about

```
PUT /icu
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "icu_analyzer" : {
          "char_filter": [
              "icu_normalizer"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "icu_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "employee" : {
      "properties": {
        "about":{
          "type": "text", 
          "analyzer": "icu_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

test the custom analyzer using followings DSLJson

```
POST /icu/_analyze
{
  "text": "สวัสดี ผมมาจากกรุงเทพฯ",
  "analyzer": "icu_analyzer"
}
```

The result should be [สวัสดี, ผม, มา, จาก, กรุงเทพฯ]

My suggestion would be :

```
Kibana : Dev Tool could help you for effective query crafting
```